# Vue 2 : Error: CSS minification error: Parse error on line 1

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am facing this error while trying to build the project

### ` ERROR  Error: CSS minification error: Parse error on line 1:
...rfont-size, calc(1 * var(--sjs-font-size, var(--sjs-font-size, 16px))))

### Expecting end of input, "ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", got unexpected "RPAREN". File: css/chunk-05ee5b2b.8e9c8e20.css
Error: CSS minification error: Parse error on line 1:
...rfont-size, calc(1 * var(--sjs-font-size, var(--sjs-font-size, 16px))))

Expecting end of input, "ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", got unexpected "RPAREN". File: css/chunk-05ee5b2b.8e9c8e20.css
at F:\folder\Project-name\node_modules@intervolga\optimize-cssnano-plugin\index.js:106:21
at async Promise.all (index 4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angle@0.0.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angle@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-15T17_46_04_644Z-debug.log`

i am using vue 2.5.17

**steps i done to resolve**
-searched for the style written in the error but it wasn't found in the project
-comment all the inline style as i saw in another topic but it didn't work for the project

so does anyone have a clue ?